# Script to read from Excel and interact with website and write down the result again to Excel

Tags: excel, autoit

I am trying to automate some repetitive work for getting results from a website,
this link [Drugs.com](http://drugs.com/drug_interactions.php), checks for interaction between two medicines.
I must take the text of the two medicines from the Excel sheet and enter them on the website to check the interaction between them.
Here is a sample of my Excel sheet:

```
column(A)         Column(B)
(A1)candesartan       benazepril
(A2)eprosartan        captopril
(A3)irbesartan        enalapril
```

When I press 'Check For Interaction' the result of the next page must be extracted and return one of tree interactions:

-major
-moderate
-minor

This must then write the result to column(c)

I am a beginner at autoit but I can do some scripting albeit with a lot of bugs. 
I will appreciate it if someone can correct/assist me with the bugs in my code. I will also appreciate it if someone can help me with the correct keywords so that I can Google for examples and solutions.
Thanks all.

```
  #include <Excel.au3>
#include <IE.au3>
#include <File.au3>

Local $sWorkbook = "C:\Users\Aligaaly\Desktop\autoit\test\drugs.xlsx"
Local $oExcel = _Excel_Open()
Local $oWorkbook = _Excel_BookOpen($oExcel, $sWorkbook)
$oWorkbook = _Excel_BookAttach($sWorkbook)


GLOBAL $oIE = _IECreate("https://www.drugs.com/drug_interactions.php")
Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input")

For $oInput In $oInputs
      $text_form1 = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "livesearch-interaction")
      If StringLower($oInput.classname) == "input-button search-button" and _IEFormElementGetValue($oInput)  Then ; it is an input
                  Global $oInput_btn = $oInput
      EndIf
Next


WinActivate("[CLASS:XLMAIN]", "")

For $i = 1 To 5
Global $sResulta = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, 'A' & $i & ':A' & $i,1 )

      For $y = 1 To 5
      Global $sResultb = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, 'B' & $y & ':B' & $y,1 )

               WinActivate("[CLASS:IEFrame]", "")
               _IEFormElementSetValue($text_form1,  $sResulta )
               _IEAction ($oInput_btn, "click")
            sleep(5000)
               _IEFormElementSetValue($text_form1,  $sResultb )
               _IEAction ($oInput_btn, "click")
            sleep(5000)


            For $oInput In $oInputs
                  If StringLower($oInput.value) == "check for interactions" Then
                        Global $check_btn = $oInput
                  EndIf
            Next
           _IEAction ($check_btn, "click")


            sleep(5000)

            $oButtonsa = _IETagnameGetCollection($oIE, "span")
            For $oButtonn in $oButtonsa
                If $oButtonn.classname == "status-category status-category-major" Then
                        WinActivate("[CLASS:XLMAIN]", "")
                        _Excel_RangeWrite($oWorkbook, $oWorkbook.Activesheet, "major","C" & $y)
                ElseIf $oButtonn.classname == "status-category status-category-moderate" Then
                        WinActivate("[CLASS:XLMAIN]", "")
                        _Excel_RangeWrite($oWorkbook, $oWorkbook.Activesheet, "moderate","C" & $y)
                ElseIf $oButtonn.classname == "status-category status-category-minor" Then
                        WinActivate("[CLASS:XLMAIN]", "")
                        _Excel_RangeWrite($oWorkbook, $oWorkbook.Activesheet, "minor","C" & $y)
              EndIf
                ExitLoop

            Next
         Next
Next
```

i have updated the code with my final touches 
i think this code is now complete the steps i have write down above 
but i have an error when the script finish the first iteration 
[image]

Comment: What does the URL of the result page look like? It's entirely possible that you can submit a URL directly and get the result then scrape the results off that page. This would mean you could do this through directly submitting and scraping data rather than searching for fields and buttons and stuff

Comment: unfortunately the link has id's i donot know what is it refer to  sample of the result link
https://www.drugs.com/interactions-check.php?drug_list=917-482,11-2692

Comment: hmmm in that case probably stick with Autoit. I don't actually see the code in your error message in your script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in _IEFormElementSetValue function.

Probably,

```
$text_form1 = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "livesearch-interaction")
```

can't find any object.

For debug it you can insert this code before _IEFormElementSetValue:

```
ConsoleWrite("isObject:" & isObj($text_form1) & @CRLF)
```

**Update:** I found 3 problems.
1) You didn't return to search page after end of iteration and the input object can't be found;
2) You must get Input and Button object on the start of each iteration;
3) Exitloop must be on each If ... esleif section.

Try this code:

```
#include <Excel.au3>
#include <IE.au3>
#include <File.au3>

Local $sWorkbook = "C:\Users\Aligaaly\Desktop\autoit\test\drugs.xlsx"
Local $oExcel = _Excel_Open()
Local $oWorkbook = _Excel_BookOpen($oExcel, $sWorkbook)
$oWorkbook = _Excel_BookAttach($sWorkbook)


GLOBAL $oIE = _IECreate("https://www.drugs.com/drug_interactions.php")
Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input")

For $oInput In $oInputs
      $text_form1 = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "livesearch-interaction")
      If StringLower($oInput.classname) == "input-button search-button" and _IEFormElementGetValue($oInput)  Then ; it is an input
                  Global $oInput_btn = $oInput
      EndIf
Next


WinActivate("[CLASS:XLMAIN]", "")

For $i = 1 To 5
    Global $sResulta = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, 'A' & $i & ':A' & $i,1 )

          For $y = 1 To 5
          Global $sResultb = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, 'B' & $y & ':B' & $y,1 )

                $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input")

                For $oInput In $oInputs
                      $text_form1 = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "livesearch-interaction")
                      If StringLower($oInput.classname) == "input-button search-button" and _IEFormElementGetValue($oInput)  Then ; it is an input
                            $oInput_btn = $oInput
                      EndIf
                Next

                   WinActivate("[CLASS:IEFrame]", "")
                   _IEFormElementSetValue($text_form1,  $sResulta )
                   _IEAction ($oInput_btn, "click")
                sleep(5000)
                   _IEFormElementSetValue($text_form1,  $sResultb )
                   _IEAction ($oInput_btn, "click")
                sleep(5000)


                For $oInput In $oInputs
                      If StringLower($oInput.value) == "check for interactions" Then
                            Global $check_btn = $oInput
                      EndIf
                Next
               _IEAction ($check_btn, "click")


                sleep(5000)

                $oButtonsa = _IETagnameGetCollection($oIE, "span")
                For $oButtonn in $oButtonsa
                    If $oButtonn.classname == "status-category status-category-major" Then
                            WinActivate("[CLASS:XLMAIN]", "")
                            _Excel_RangeWrite($oWorkbook, $oWorkbook.Activesheet, "major","C" & $y)
                            ExitLoop
                    ElseIf $oButtonn.classname == "status-category status-category-moderate" Then
                            WinActivate("[CLASS:XLMAIN]", "")
                            _Excel_RangeWrite($oWorkbook, $oWorkbook.Activesheet, "moderate","C" & $y)
                            ExitLoop
                    ElseIf $oButtonn.classname == "status-category status-category-minor" Then
                            WinActivate("[CLASS:XLMAIN]", "")
                            _Excel_RangeWrite($oWorkbook, $oWorkbook.Activesheet, "minor","C" & $y)
                            ExitLoop
                  EndIf      

                Next
                _IENavigate($oIE, "https://www.drugs.com/drug_interactions.php?action=new_list")
             Next
    Next
```